# Backslashes not working properly in my web service

Tags: c#, backslash, string-literals

I have a simple line of code in a web service:

```
instance = @"\instanceNameHere";
```

Yet the output is always the same.

```
\\instanceNameHere
```

If I remove the @ and use two slashes, I get the same result. I've never seen this before and my Google-fu has failed me. I even wrote a simple app and the result was correct. So why is it acting up in the web service?

Comment: What do you mean by "the output"?  Are you viewing this perhaps in the debugger?

Comment: Well web service isn't the same as folder directory, folder and file paths normally have single slash. What are you trying to do, just determine why there are two slashed? Look at network drives you need to specify double slash.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's escaping the slash for you in the debugger so you know that it's a slash and not an escape sequence like `\t`. If the debugger did not do this, how could you distinguish the string

```
\t
```

from the string

```
<tab>
```

in the debugger since the latter is represented in an escape sequence by `\t`? Therefor the former is shown as

```
\\t
```

and the latter as

```
\t
```

Write it to a stream or the console and you'll see that it only has one slash, or do `instance.Length` and compare to a count of the characters. You'll see `17` on the console, whereas `\\instanceNameHere` has eighteen characters.

Comment: Ugh. That was it. In my little test program I wrote it out to the console, hence why it looked right there. Never knew that about the debugger. Makes sense. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The debugger displays strings as C# literals.  So it's displaying them with characters escaped.  It would also show carriage returns as `\r` and tabs as `\t`.  This is purely for visualization -- the string does not literally contain these escape characters.  If you write it out to a log, it will not include the escape characters -- it will look as you expect.

Answer (score -2):

A UNC name of any format, which always start with two backslash characters ("\").

[Link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365247%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Update : Please see @Jason post above! I didn't realise he was checking in the debugger.

Comment: I don't think he is talking about UNC Names.  That's just how you escape a "/" in C#, which is what the debugger is displaying.

Comment: I see that, his comment were he was looking in Debugger. Oh well.